# Adanet problem: Failed to remove a directory

Tags: python, tensorflow

need some help with adanet.

I'm very new with tensorflow and adanet and trying to create some simple case.
I've created data in matlab and load it in python for adanet train and test.
And I see some strange bahaviour: code is failing about 4-5 times before it get correct output. `Outputs error: "FailedPreconditionError: Failed to remove a directory:` `D:\python\adanet\test_1\log\learn_mixture_weights_with_complexity_regularization 1\temp_model_dir; Directory not empty"`

Code is attached.

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

import functools
import os
import scipy.io as sio

import adanet
import tensorflow as tf

# The random seed to use.
RANDOM_SEED = 42

LOG_DIR = 'D:\\python\\adanet\\test_1\\log'

mat_contents = sio.loadmat('data.mat')
x_train = mat_contents['x_train']
y_train = mat_contents['y_train']
x_test  = mat_contents['x_test']
y_test  = mat_contents['y_test']


#(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = (
#    tf.keras.datasets.boston_housing.load_data())

# Preview the first example from the training data
print('Model inputs: %s \n' % x_train[0])
print('Model output: %s ' % (y_train[0]))



FEATURES_KEY = "x"


def input_fn(partition, training, batch_size):
  """Generate an input function for the Estimator."""

  def _input_fn():
#tf.log1p
    if partition == "train":
      dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(({
          FEATURES_KEY: x_train
      }, y_train))
    else:
      dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(({
          FEATURES_KEY: x_test
      }, y_test))

    # We call repeat after shuffling, rather than before, to prevent separate
    # epochs from blending together.
    if training:
      dataset = dataset.shuffle(10 * batch_size, seed=RANDOM_SEED).repeat()

    dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)
    iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
    features, labels = iterator.get_next()
    return features, labels

  return _input_fn



_NUM_LAYERS_KEY = "num_layers"


class _SimpleDNNBuilder(adanet.subnetwork.Builder):
  """Builds a DNN subnetwork for AdaNet."""

  def __init__(self, optimizer, layer_size, num_layers, learn_mixture_weights,
               seed):
    """Initializes a `_DNNBuilder`.

    Args:
      optimizer: An `Optimizer` instance for training both the subnetwork and
        the mixture weights.
      layer_size: The number of nodes to output at each hidden layer.
      num_layers: The number of hidden layers.
      learn_mixture_weights: Whether to solve a learning problem to find the
        best mixture weights, or use their default value according to the
        mixture weight type. When `False`, the subnetworks will return a no_op
        for the mixture weight train op.
      seed: A random seed.

    Returns:
      An instance of `_SimpleDNNBuilder`.
    """

    self._optimizer = optimizer
    self._layer_size = layer_size
    self._num_layers = num_layers
    self._learn_mixture_weights = learn_mixture_weights
    self._seed = seed

  def build_subnetwork(self,
                       features,
                       logits_dimension,
                       training,
                       iteration_step,
                       summary,
                       previous_ensemble=None):
    """See `adanet.subnetwork.Builder`."""

    input_layer = tf.to_float(features[FEATURES_KEY])
    kernel_initializer = tf.glorot_uniform_initializer(seed=self._seed)
    last_layer = input_layer
    for _ in range(self._num_layers):
      last_layer = tf.layers.dense(
          last_layer,
          units=self._layer_size,
          activation=tf.nn.relu,
          kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer)
    logits = tf.layers.dense(
        last_layer,
        units=logits_dimension,
        kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer)

    persisted_tensors = {_NUM_LAYERS_KEY: tf.constant(self._num_layers)}
    return adanet.Subnetwork(
        last_layer=last_layer,
        logits=logits,
        complexity=self._measure_complexity(),
        persisted_tensors=persisted_tensors)

  def _measure_complexity(self):
    """Approximates Rademacher complexity as the square-root of the depth."""
    return tf.sqrt(tf.to_float(self._num_layers))

  def build_subnetwork_train_op(self, subnetwork, loss, var_list, labels,
                                iteration_step, summary, previous_ensemble):
    """See `adanet.subnetwork.Builder`."""
    return self._optimizer.minimize(loss=loss, var_list=var_list)

  def build_mixture_weights_train_op(self, loss, var_list, logits, labels,
                                     iteration_step, summary):
    """See `adanet.subnetwork.Builder`."""

    if not self._learn_mixture_weights:
      return tf.no_op()
    return self._optimizer.minimize(loss=loss, var_list=var_list)

  @property
  def name(self):
    """See `adanet.subnetwork.Builder`."""

    if self._num_layers == 0:
      # A DNN with no hidden layers is a linear model.
      return "linear"
    return "{}_layer_dnn".format(self._num_layers)


class SimpleDNNGenerator(adanet.subnetwork.Generator):
  """Generates a two DNN subnetworks at each iteration.

  The first DNN has an identical shape to the most recently added subnetwork
  in `previous_ensemble`. The second has the same shape plus one more dense
  layer on top. This is similar to the adaptive network presented in Figure 2 of
  [Cortes et al. ICML 2017](https://arxiv.org/abs/1607.01097), without the
  connections to hidden layers of networks from previous iterations.
  """

  def __init__(self,
               optimizer,
               layer_size=64,
               learn_mixture_weights=False,
               seed=None):
    """Initializes a DNN `Generator`.

    Args:
      optimizer: An `Optimizer` instance for training both the subnetwork and
        the mixture weights.
      layer_size: Number of nodes in each hidden layer of the subnetwork
        candidates. Note that this parameter is ignored in a DNN with no hidden
        layers.
      learn_mixture_weights: Whether to solve a learning problem to find the
        best mixture weights, or use their default value according to the
        mixture weight type. When `False`, the subnetworks will return a no_op
        for the mixture weight train op.
      seed: A random seed.

    Returns:
      An instance of `Generator`.
    """

    self._seed = seed
    self._dnn_builder_fn = functools.partial(
        _SimpleDNNBuilder,
        optimizer=optimizer,
        layer_size=layer_size,
        learn_mixture_weights=learn_mixture_weights)

  def generate_candidates(self, previous_ensemble, iteration_number,
                          previous_ensemble_reports, all_reports):
    """See `adanet.subnetwork.Generator`."""

    num_layers = 0
    seed = self._seed
    if previous_ensemble:
      num_layers = tf.contrib.util.constant_value(
          previous_ensemble.weighted_subnetworks[
              -1].subnetwork.persisted_tensors[_NUM_LAYERS_KEY])
    if seed is not None:
      seed += iteration_number
    return [
        self._dnn_builder_fn(num_layers=num_layers, seed=seed),
        self._dnn_builder_fn(num_layers=num_layers + 1, seed=seed),
    ]



def serving_input_receiver_fn():
    """Serving input_fn that builds features from placeholders

    Returns
    -------
    tf.estimator.export.ServingInputReceiver
    """
    number = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[None, 1], name='number')
    receiver_tensors = {'number': number}
    features = tf.tile(number, multiples=[1, 2])
    return tf.estimator.export.ServingInputReceiver(features, receiver_tensors)




#@title AdaNet parameters
LEARNING_RATE = 0.001  #@param {type:"number"}
TRAIN_STEPS = 10000  #@param {type:"integer"}
BATCH_SIZE = 27  #@param {type:"integer"}

LEARN_MIXTURE_WEIGHTS = False  #@param {type:"boolean"}
ADANET_LAMBDA = 0  #@param {type:"number"}
ADANET_ITERATIONS = 4  #@param {type:"integer"}



def train_and_evaluate(experiment_name, learn_mixture_weights=LEARN_MIXTURE_WEIGHTS,
                       adanet_lambda=ADANET_LAMBDA):
  """Trains an `adanet.Estimator` to predict housing prices."""

  model_dir = os.path.join(LOG_DIR, experiment_name)

  estimator = adanet.Estimator(
      # Since we are predicting housing prices, we'll use a regression
      # head that optimizes for MSE.
      head=tf.contrib.estimator.regression_head(
          loss_reduction=tf.losses.Reduction.SUM_OVER_BATCH_SIZE),

      # Define the generator, which defines our search space of subnetworks
      # to train as candidates to add to the final AdaNet model.
      subnetwork_generator=SimpleDNNGenerator(
          optimizer=tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(learning_rate=LEARNING_RATE),
          learn_mixture_weights=learn_mixture_weights,
          seed=RANDOM_SEED),

      # Lambda is a the strength of complexity regularization. A larger
      # value will penalize more complex subnetworks.
      adanet_lambda=adanet_lambda,

      # The number of train steps per iteration.
      max_iteration_steps=TRAIN_STEPS // ADANET_ITERATIONS,

      # The evaluator will evaluate the model on the full training set to
      # compute the overall AdaNet loss (train loss + complexity
      # regularization) to select the best candidate to include in the
      # final AdaNet model.
      evaluator=adanet.Evaluator(
          input_fn=input_fn("train", training=False, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)),

      # Configuration for Estimators.
      config=tf.estimator.RunConfig(
          save_summary_steps=10000,
          save_checkpoints_steps=10000,
          tf_random_seed=RANDOM_SEED,
          model_dir=model_dir))

  # Train and evaluate using using the tf.estimator tooling.
  train_spec = tf.estimator.TrainSpec(
      input_fn=input_fn("train", training=True, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE),
      max_steps=TRAIN_STEPS)
  eval_spec = tf.estimator.EvalSpec(
      input_fn=input_fn("test", training=False, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE),
      steps=None,
      start_delay_secs=1,
      throttle_secs=30,
  )

  jaja = tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(estimator, train_spec, eval_spec)

  return estimator



def ensemble_architecture(result):
  """Extracts the ensemble architecture from evaluation results."""

  architecture = result["architecture/adanet/ensembles"]
  # The architecture is a serialized Summary proto for TensorBoard.
  summary_proto = tf.summary.Summary.FromString(architecture)
  return summary_proto.value[0].tensor.string_val[0]

#%%

#@test {"skip": true}
result_est = train_and_evaluate("learn_mixture_weights_with_complexity_regularization 1", learn_mixture_weights=True, adanet_lambda=.015)
```

Outputs error: "FailedPreconditionError: Failed to remove a directory: D:\python\adanet\test_1\log\learn_mixture_weights_with_complexity_regularization 1\temp_model_dir; Directory not empty"

Comment: Update: I suppose this error appears, when the new dnn layer is generated, cuz i have 4 layers in generated network, and it had failed 4 times.